# Construct graph from data file

Tags: python, dataframe, graph

I have a text file with data as below:

`A    D   15
B    A   11
C    H    2
.    .    .
.    .    .`

I read data using Dataframe in Python. Then I want to create a graph with vertices in columns 1 & 2 and column 3 is the weight.

How can I create a graph from the data? 
Thank you!

Comment: You want to plot a graph or store it in a variable? Look for NetworkX library.

Comment: @Serenity I want to store it in variable

Comment: @Dadep : How is that even distantly connected to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example using `networkx`:

```
import networkx as nx

node_list = list(set(list(df['col1']) + list(df['col2'])))  
data = [tuple(x) for x in df.values.tolist()]
# [('A', 'D', 15), ('B', 'A', 11), ('C', 'H', 2), . . .]

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(node_list)
G.add_weighted_edges_from(data)
```